# Intuition for curves of self-intersection in F-Theory

Tags: string-theory, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to study some papers on [F-Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-theory) where the standard language of communication involves ideas and terminology from algebraic geometry, specifically [intersection theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory).

As a concrete example of a possibly very trivial question, I would like to know how to think about so-called "-1 curves" and "-2 curves" (where presumably the -1 and -2 are the self-intersection numbers). What is the right way to think about these objects? (Also on the physics side, these things are supposed to connect to gauge theories and in some cases, quiver gauge theories..with the quiver pattern suggested by the intersection pattern of the curves themselves...)

A reference for this sort of question is page 9 and Figure 2 on page 15 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05565.pdf) ([arXiv:hep-th/1511.05565](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05565.pdf)) entitled "F-Theory and the Classification of Little Strings".

Comment: Have a look here for a geometrical meaning of negative self-intersection: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51193/geometric-motivation-for-negative-self-intersection

Comment: I'm not sure what else you are asking, and my F-theory days are too long ago to give a proper answer anyway. But matter in F-theory lives on matter surfaces, which are the elliptic fibration restricted to matter curves in the base. The fiber over the matter curve decomposes into components such that their intersection numbers give the Cartan matrix of a Lie algebra (one draws those with Dynkin diagrams). In the low-energy limit, this corresponds to a gauge theory with the respective gauge group.

Comment: Thanks @Noiralef! But can also you suggest more references perhaps?

Comment: The only one I can think of right now is https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3497

Comment: I've seen this review before. I didn't find much about the intersection theory aspects here, probably because those are more recent developments? But thanks, maybe I can dig up more recent references using it.

Comment: [I would write a pn instead, but SE doesn't have pns, right?] You're right, there isn't much about it there. I did my master's thesis on F-theory and never had a deep understanding of these matters, I think. If you want to understand what the intersection product means mathematically, you can try to read Hartshorne chapter V.1. For me it was enough to know that intersection in homology is dual to the wedge product of the cohomology classes, that way I could calculate stuff ;)